# How did they know 10 million dollars were taken?

Tags: plot-explanation, sabotage

In the movie Sabotage they steal 10 million dollars from the 200 million dollars and Arnold blows the money up. So how do the investigators know 10 million were stolen in the next scene when the investigators are drilling them all about why they stole 10 million but the money was all blown up
.

Answer (score 1):

I actually thought about that as well and the only answer that I could come up with was that it's just an inconsistency in the plot...

They obviously blew up the pile of money to prevent anyone from finding out that they grabbed a part of it, which is quite clever as there's really no way to find out how much of it that was lost in the explosion. The only way that the DEA could have found out about it was if someone snitched, but there's just no one in the team that would have done that. When the 10 million dollars went missing there was one person who took it a tad bit harder than everyone else, but bringing in the DEA made it worse for everyone so there's really nothing good that could have come out of it.

My guess is that the whole DEA part of the movie was added to the script after the first scene was written, and then they just never went back and changed it.

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that the person who found and took it, informed the DEA that it had been taken.

All I know for sure is, the writing was a bit sloppy.  It was really just a vehicle to get Arnold back in the Action game, although there wasn't much action (in a stuntman sort of way).

Comment: That would be Arnold then. I'm not saying that's unreasonable, in fact it could make some sense. But if that's what you're saying, maybe you can elaborate a little more how this helped his situation.